# How can I draw an errorbar graph without lines and points in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I am currently using the following code to plot errorbar graphs.

```
plt.errorbar(log_I_mean_, log_V2_mean_, xerr, yerr, '.')
```

However, the end result shows a circular point in the center of each errorbar intersection point. How can I plot just the errorbars without the central point, as is required in scientific work?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar)?

Answer (score 3):

use `'none'` instead of `'.'`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0.1, 4, 0.5)
y = np.exp(-x)

yerr = 0.1 + 0.2*np.sqrt(x)
xerr = 0.1 + yerr

plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(x, y, 0.2, 0.4,'none')
plt.title("Simplest errorbars, 0.2 in x, 0.4 in y")
```

result:

[image]

P.S. this is slightly modified version of part of the example of pylab [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_demo.html)